# Loading images and text in pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

Im not sure what this is called, so its hard to lookup. I want to get a set of images that have a unique identifier and the put some corresponding text information next to it, inside of an application.  When more images are loading a scroll bar can go through them.  I dont know which methods or how this is possible.  For example, through other threads i found how to load images using a list widget and switching the items to an icon.  However with this method I dont see how to put text next to it.  Can this be done with a table, or a tree?  I have been using qt Designer but I dont see anything like this available.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#QListWidgetItem-3)?

Comment: thats what im currently using to load images as 'icons', but i dont see a way of controlling rows and columns for left to be image and right side to be different lines of text fields

Comment: If you need that type of customization in one item as opposed to two distinct, I would say, go for an own delegate?

Comment: i just looked into that and it looks good.  I will see how far the qlistwidget will take me, if i can get the text aligned where i need it.  thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QListWidget` for that. Each item would represent an image (item's icon) and all text to the right of it. Define `iconSize` property of list widget to enlarge item icons. Use `\n` in item texts to add line breaks.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt realize the new line character worked for that.  this seems the easiest to do for now